# Fail to call a Json web service inside my asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I want to call the following webservice as mentioend on this link http://dev.joget.org/community/display/KB/JSON+API#JSONAPI-web%2Fjson%2Fworkflow%2Fprocess%2Flist

So inside my asp.net mvc view i wrote the folloiwng:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Send an AJAX request
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin",
                function (data) {
                    // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                        // Format the text to display.
                        var str = val.id + ': $' + val.packageName;

                        // Add a list item for the product.
                        $('<li/>', { text: str })
                        .appendTo($('#products'));
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
<h1>The Processes are</h1>
<ul id="products"/>
```

But when i run the above web page no processes will be displayed under the `<h1>The Processes are </h1>` , while if i type the following `http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin&nbsp`; directly on the address-bar of my browser then all the processes will be displayed. so what might be going wrong ?

BR

**-::::UPDATED::::-**
i HAVE UPDATED MY JAVASCRIPT TO BE AS FOLLOW:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list?loginAs=admin",

               dataType: "JSONP",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (data) {
                   $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                       // Format the text to display.
                       var str = val.packageId + ': $ ' + val.packageName;

                       // Add a list item for the product.
                       $('<li/>', { text: str })
                       .appendTo($('#products'));

                   });
               }});
           });
```

but the result of the web service call is returned as

```
undefined: $ undefined
```

instead of being something such as:-

```
{"activityId":"","processId":"289_process1"}
```

So what is the problem that is preventing my code from displaying the right data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the JSONP `callback` parameter as `callback=?` at the end of your query string as explained in the documentation:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        // Format the text to display.
        var str = val.id + ': $' + val.packageName;
        // Add a list item for the product.
        $('<li/>', { text: str }).appendTo('#products');
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

After showing your JSON (at last) the list of products is contained within a `data` property, so you need to adapt your `$.each` and operate on this property and not directly on the result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "packageName": "CRM",
            "packageI‌​d": "crm"
        },
        {
            "packageName": "EngineersAssociation",
            "packageId": "EngineersAssociation"
        },
        {
            "packageName": "LeaveApp",
            "packageId": "leaveApp"
        },
        {
            "packageName": "Newtest",
            "packageId": "Newtest"
        },
        {
            "p‌​ackageName": "TestApp",
            "packageId": "testapp"
        },
        {
            "packageName": "test54",
            "packageId": "test5"
        }
    ]
}
```

So adapt your code:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=admin&callback=?';
$.getJSON(url, function (result) {
    // On success, 'result.data' contains a list of products.
    $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
        // Format the text to display.
        var str = val.id + ': $' + val.packageName;
        // Add a list item for the product.
        $('<li/>', { text: str }).appendTo('#products');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for you reply; i tried your code, but the web page will keep loading without any results !!!

Comment: might the problem is that the two application are on different ports on at http://localhost:2834/ while the other is at 'http://localhost:8080 ??? Or this should not cause any problem

Comment: This should not be a problem if the web service supports JSONP.

Comment: so what might be the problem then ?

Comment: The remote web service might be returning JSON and not JSONP. You should debug your AJAX call with FireBug to see any potential errors during the request.

Comment: What did you see in FireBug? What's the resulting JSON that you received from the remote server?

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but where i should be looking inside the FireBug ?, if inside the HTML tab the JSON is returned as "undefined" ...

Comment: Look at the `Net` tab where you must see the AJAX request. Actually it's not really an AJAX request in your case because you are using JSONP, but anyway you should see it there.

Comment: i got the following. Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges bytes
Content-Length 3030
Content-Type application/javascript
Date Wed, 10 Oct 2012 07:54:33 GMT
Etag "8d422277bca6cd1:0"
Last-Modified Wed, 10 Oct 2012 07:54:24 GMT
Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcbS5naGF3aVxkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDEyXFByb2plY3RzXE12Y0FwcGxpY2F0aW9uMlxNdmNBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjJcU2NyaXB0c1xmLmpz?=

Comment: Could you show the JSON response? You have shown only the headers.

Comment: and on the response tab i will get the following . jQuery17102251782537793271_1349856095995({"data":[{"packageName":"CRM","packageId":"crm"},{"packageName":" Engineers Association","packageId":"EngineersAssociation"},{"packageName":"Leave App","packageId":"leaveApp"},{"packageName":"Newtest","packageId":"Newtest"},{"packageName":"Test App","packageId":"testapp"},{"packageName":"test54","packageId":"test5"}]})

Comment: Alright, this seems fine to me. Is the `success` callback invoked?

Comment: and on the JSOn tab.  

[Object { packageName=

"CRM"

,  packageId=

"crm"

}, Object { packageName=

"Engineers Association"

,  packageId=

"EngineersAssociation"

}, Object { packageName=

"Leave App"

,  packageId=

"leaveApp"

}, . SO IT SEEMS THE JSON IS CORRECT, BUT IT IS BEING DISPLAYED AS UNDEFINED ON THE HTML. AND IN MY CASE THERE ARE 5 JSON OBJECTS WHILE ONLY ONE "UNDEFINED" ROW WILL BE SHOWN IN THE HTML.